# How to setup more complicated (IoC like) registration in AutoFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

Is it possible to reuse production IoC container registration in integration tests when using AutoFixture?

The problem is that I need the following fixture setup to inject mocks if dependency is not registered and inject "real" database related dependencies

```
var fixture = new Fixture().WithMocks().WithRealDatabase()
```

The solution I've tried

```
internal static Fixture WithMocks(this Fixture fixture)
{
    fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
}

internal static Fixture WithRealDatabase(this Fixture fixture)
{
    var containerBuilder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
    ...
    containerBuilder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
    containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces()        
    containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    ...
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new ContainerSpecimenBuilder(containerBuilder.Build()));
}

internal class ContainerSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly IContainer container;

    public ContainerSpecimenBuilder(IContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var seededRequest = request as SeededRequest;

        if (seededRequest == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        var result = this.container.ResolveOptional(seededRequest.Request as Type);
        return result ?? new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

But the problem with this approach is that `container.Resolve` will not take into account already registered dependencies in AutoFixture.

Is there any alternative to solve this problem to have more complicated registrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach looks sound, but you should add the `ContainerSpecimenBuilder` to `ResidueCollectors` instead of to `Customizations`:

```
fixture.ResidueCollectors.Add(new ContainerSpecimenBuilder(containerBuilder.Build()));
```

`AutoMoqCustomization` also adds a node to `ResidueCollectors`, so you may need to experiment a bit with the specific ordering to figure out exactly how to make it behave like you want it to behave. [The ordering matters](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/31/TheorderofAutoFixtureCustomizationsmatter).

For more information about the difference between `Customizations` and `ResidueCollectors`, see the [AutoFixture architecture documentation](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Internal-Architecture).

---

A slightly simpler (and safer?) implementation of `ContainerSpecimenBuilder` could be just handling requests for `Type` instances directly, instead of for `SeededRequest`, as almost all `SeededRequest` values are relayed to requests for `Type` objects anyway:

```
internal class ContainerSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly IContainer container;

    public ContainerSpecimenBuilder(IContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var t = request as Type;

        if (t == null)
            return new NoSpecimen(request);

        var result = this.container.ResolveOptional(t);
        return result ?? new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark, thank you for support, it was as simple as using ResidueCollectors instead of Customization, plus changing order of fixture customization. to put container specimen builder first.