# Can AutoFixture register interfaces via convention?

Tags: c#, autofixture

My application is using simple injector to handle my ioc.
I have some code like below that will do some automatic registration.

```
RegisterForAssembly(container, webApiLifestyle, typeof(IAddEntityCommand).Assembly, "MyProj.CommandQuery.Commands");
RegisterForAssembly(container, webApiLifestyle, typeof(IGetAllEntityQuery).Assembly, "MyProj.CommandQuery.Queries");

private static void RegisterForAssembly(Container container, WebApiRequestLifestyle webApiLifestyle, Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
{
    var registrations =
       from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
       where type.Namespace == nameSpace
       where type.GetInterfaces().Any()
       select new { InterfaceType = type.GetInterfaces().Single(), ConcreteType = type };

     foreach (var reg in registrations)
     {
        container.Register(reg.InterfaceType, reg.ConcreteType, webApiLifestyle);
     }
}
```

It's basically looking in an assembly and pairing any interface with it's concrete for a namespace.

I was hoping to achieve something similar using AutoFixture

```
    private static void RegisterForAssembly(Fixture fixture, Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
    {
        var registrations =
            from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            where type.Namespace == nameSpace
            where type.GetInterfaces().Any()
            select new { InterfaceType = type.GetInterfaces().Single(), ConcreteType = type };

        foreach (var reg in registrations)
        {
            //fixture.Register... ???
            //fixture.Register<reg.InterfaceType>(() => fixture.Create<reg.ConcreteType>();
        }
    }
```

I then wondered if I was reinventing the wheel and it may be something that is built in, however I can not find anything in the documentation.

==
Short version ==

I want to configure auto fixture to give me the correct concrete for a given interface without registering them all individually.

Comment: You can certainly [setup AutoFixture to map interfaces to concrete types](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/06/MappingtypeswithAutoFixture/) like you did in your example, but I do question whether that is the right thing to do. AutoFixture is a test data builder and, as such, is aimed at creating and populating objects with state rather than objects with behavior. An interface defines _behavior_ rather than state. Do your interfaces maybe contain properties that you want AutoFixture to assign?

Comment: I am using AutoFixture to create me an api controller for which there are some dependencies. These are mappers, queries etc that i would like it to give me the real implementations for. There are times when i will want a mock but by default i want the real thing which i can then override to be a mock when needed (date / current user providers for example)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31740092/126014

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`TypeRelay`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Kernel/TypeRelay.cs) instances for this. For each pair you can do something like:

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(anInterfaceType, aConcreteType));
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution would be to associate a concrete type with *all* of the interfaces it implements. This way you won't have to manually add new registrations as your types implement additional interfaces.

In order to do this, you first need to create a *type relay* based on a filter:

```
public class FilteringTypeRelay : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly IRequestSpecification filter;
    private readonly Type target;

    public FilteringTypeRelay(IRequestSpecification filter, Type target)
    {
        this.filter = filter;
        this.target = target;
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        return this.filter.IsSatisfiedBy(request)
            ? context.Resolve(this.target)
            : new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

At this point, you can associate a type with its interfaces using the built-in [`ImplementedInterfaceSpecification`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Kernel/ImplementedInterfaceSpecification.cs):

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new FilteringTypeRelay(
        new ImplementedInterfaceSpecification(typeof(ConcreteType)),
        typeof(ConcreteType)));
```

AutoFixture will then create an instance of `ConcreteType` every time it encounters *any* of its implemented interfaces, present or future.

Comment: AutoFixture already *almost* has this class: [FilteringSpecimenBuilder](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Kernel/FilteringSpecimenBuilder.cs). You could use that as a building block. If so, you'd only need to create a small `ISpecimenBuilder` that resolves the `target`, and then compose it into a `FilteringSpecimenBuilder`.